# Stop service during boot

Tags: boot, services

Ok I did a stupid thing. I created a script file which is suppose to change permission on a folder during boot up. Instead the script is changing permissions on the root path ("/") and all sub-folders.

I have a back up which I recovered from, but when I boot, the script file runs again and changes all the permissions on root folder.

Is there a way to disable this script from running during booting phase?

Comment: use a live dvd and delete the script. or rename it. or at least move it from the boot up process.

Comment: Thanks that worked. But I guess i ran the script prior to my backup. All permission messed up on my root. Lesson learned on this one.